# Android Location Manager Issue

Tags: android, gps, location, status

From the following code, I get the current location.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
GlobalLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

After getting the location I draw the location overlays on Google map and from location provider I decide the color of location overlays. Here is the following code which decide the color on the base of Location Provider.

```
    Serviceprovider = GlobalLocation.getProvider();
    if(Serviceprovider.equals("network"))
    {
         positionOverlay.iColor = 2;
    }//End if
    else if(Serviceprovider.equals("gps"))
    {
         positionOverlay.iColor = 1;
    }//End else if
```

Everything is working fine outdoor, but the problem is, if I use my application indoor where the GPS is not stable. Provider doesn't use `network`. network provider execute only if the GPS is off. Can you kindly guide me that how can I decide the jump on network if GPS is not stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered before. You need to add two different location listeners. One for the GPS and one using the network position. Cellular network based location listener.

GPS will work only outdoors but the cellular network would work anywhere there are signals however it isn't as accurate as the GPS is.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            locationListener2 = new MyLocationListener();               
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener2);
```

Comment: how I can decide that which provider providing the location??

Comment: @Arman You basically add both listeners and one of the two will pick up your location. Reno's answer below has a very good guide. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a fix, use the `Location.getProvider()` to know which provider was used.

Use this [elaborate article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) to decide which LocationProvider is the best.