# Switch the GPS location provider automatically

Tags: android, gps

Is there any methods to automatically switch the android GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER, according to the current best provider?

Currently I'm using the following code to find the best provider and request the locationupdates using the best provider.

```
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 1.0f, locationListener);
```

Suppose while starting this the user was inside a building, so the best provider at that time will be the NETWORK_PROVIDER. After some time he moves out, now the best provider willbe gps. But I had already started fetching locations using network provider. How to fix this?

Comment: I've answered this before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711974/android-location-manager-issue/5712023#5712023

Comment: @Hades: try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the guidelines in the [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) topic. You would need to listen to both providers and then decide, which one is offering more accurate results.